# How to charge bootstrap capacitor to achieve 100% duty cycle

Tags: mosfet-driver

To be more specific, the IR2110 uses a diode and a capacitor for bootstrapping. It's not allowed to use 100% duty cycle on the high side MOSFET. How to design the circuit to charge the bootstrap capacitor and regulate its voltage (\$V_b\$,\$V_s\$) to near \$V_{cc}\$.

For more information.
I planned to use it with a IRF540 N-FET and \$V_{cc} = 12V\$

[image: circuit_1]

Comment: Is there any actual point in regulating the voltage near Vcc? Think about this please.

Comment: I mean, voltage of bootstrap will use to drive high side. if highside Vgs exceed 15V it will broke my FET. for low side Vgs it equal to Vcc.

Comment: That just seems like a [gobbledygook](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gobbledygook) response.

Comment: I need voltage between capacitor pin stay near vcc. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Capacitor pin???

Comment: I want Vb - Vs approximately equal Vcc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107995/discussion-between-m-lab-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Easiest way is to replace the cap with an isolated DC-DC converter and remove the diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using charge pump with little modification as this [Answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/151437/251254) will suit my requirment well. I can use 100% duty and highside Vgs garanty to not exceed maximum limit
[image]